# Wie sagt man "in terms of" auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation

Ich bekomme es irgendwie nicht hin, den folgenden Satz schön ins Deutsche zu übersetzen:

> The function `words` is defined in terms of primitive combinators.

Speziell geht es mir um den Teil *in terms of*. Ich finde kein Äquivalent, das die Bedeutung erhält.

Comment: Was bedeutet der Beispielsatzt bitte?

Comment: Die Funktion `words` (teilt eine Zeichenkette in Wörter auf) wurde auschließlich mit Hilfe von primitiven Kombinatoren definiert. Das ergibt einen Sinn, wenn man es auf funktionale Programmierung anwendet.

Comment: Wofür verwendest du den Satz? Technische Dokumentation? Akademische Arbeit?

Comment: @OregonGhost: Erstmal geht es mir darum den Satz in schönes Deutsch zu übersetzen - eigentlich geht es mir weniger um den Satz, sondern eher um dieses Konstrukt "in terms of". Einfach nur, um z.B. jemandem auf Deutsch das zu erklären.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Ich wollte nur darauf hinaus, dass der Satz im Deutschen, in allen Varianten, die bisher vorgestellt wurden, etwas unglücklich ist und je nach Zielpublikum sehr gestelzt oder unverständlich wirken kann.

Comment: Die selbst vorgeschlagene Übersetzung verwendet auch unmotiviert Vergangenheitsform, und fügt ein 'ausschließlich' hinzu. "Die words-Funktion ist mit Hilfe primitiver Kombinatoren definiert" scheint mir ein sauberer Ausgangspunkt.

Comment: Klingt nach Programmierung oder Mathematik. Ehrlich gesagt klingt der englische Satz für mich schon falsch, aber da ich Englisch nicht nativ spreche, mag ich mich da irren. Ich würde es mit "`als`" übersetzen: "`Die Funktion 'words' ist als primitiver Kombinator definiert`"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gelegentlich sieht man so etwas:

> Die Funktion `words` wurde auf Basis primitiver Kombinatoren definiert.

Wobei ich mich da frage, ob man mit mehr Kontextwissen den Satz eventuell komplett anders formulieren könnte.

Comment: Das gefällt mir.

Comment: Mir nicht, das klingt irgentwie kantig.

Answer (score 7):

Ich würde es so übersetzen:

> Die Funktion `Words` ist mittels primitiver Kombinatoren bestimmt.

Comment: +1 Wollte ich gerade selbst vorschlagen

Comment: Für eine Leserschaft mit mathematischem Hintergrund sicherlich gut. Je nach Zielgruppe daher aber auch etwas unglücklich. Warum *bestimmt* und nicht *definiert*? Letzteres würde ich im Rahmen von Software-Entwicklung (FUZxxl erwähnte funktionale Programmierung) bevorzugen.

Comment: @OregonGhost wollte eine Alternative bieten. Natürlich geht auch "definiert". Ich fine "bestimmt" passt hier auch und frischt den Satz etwas auf. Definieren heißt ja nichts anderes als bestimmen.

Comment: Ich erwähne das deshalb, weil in unseren Dokumentationen (also die, die ich und Kollegen zu unseren Entwicklungen schreiben) mitunter dank eines gewissen Kollegen genau solche Sätze auftauchen, die eben (in meinen Ohren, und auch in denen der Kunden) sehr mathematisch klingen. Fehlt dann nur noch "Sei X Element aus Y", dann versteht kein Kunde das mehr ;) Das kann natürlich auch gewollt sein. Bei einer akademischen Arbeit zum Thema ist das sicherlich auch genau richtig. Darauf wollte ich nur hinweisen.

Answer (score 4):

Wie wäre es mit:

> Die Funktion `words` ist mit Hilfe primitiver Kombinatoren definiert.

Edit:

[LEO](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=in%20terms%20of) sagt noch "im Bezug auf" und "vermittels".

Comment: Das Problem ist, dass sich die Bedeutung verändert. "mit Hilfe" sagt nur, dass eben jene verwendet wurden, während "in terms of" eher sagt, dass es ausschließlich diese waren.

Comment: Dann verwende doch "ausschließlich mit Hilfe".

Comment: "ausschließlich mit Hilfe" finde ich auch gelungen.

Comment: ist korrekt, aber noch nicht ganz so flüssig wie die Antwort von splattne

Comment: Muss in der Tat "ausschließlich" enthalten, ansonsten geht die eigentliche, fachspezifische Bedeutung verloren.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit "anhand von [..] definiert"? Oder "[..] beschrieben"?

Answer (score 4):

> In terms of...

- hinsichtlich
- im Sinne von
- unter ... Aspekt
- in Bezug auf
- in Form von
- mittels

Answer (score 2):

Manchmal paßt ein 'in der Sprache der'; hier jedoch nicht.

```
In terms of law: guilty. 
In der Sprache der Justiz: schuldig.
```